# Bot Don't Send Tags | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed, message

Hey i made a bot that listens to a channel, when a message has been sent in the channel the bot replaces the message with an embed with the message content, but I have some problems, when somebody tries to tag someone the bot prints this

```
(node:16552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Could not interpret "[]" as string.
    at RequestHandler.execute
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

When i add an attachment it sends the test only! And finally i want to set the author image same as the user that sends the message...

Here is my code:

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
    
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.id == "771695635598278677") {
        message.delete()
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        //let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null
        const dark = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setDescription(`${message.content}\n`)
        .addField('\n')
        .setAuthor("Twitter")
        .setImage(message.attachments)
        .setFooter('twitter', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/564032243836780558/771614643159433226/Anonymous_emblem.svg.png')
        if(isNaN(message.content)) {
            message.channel.send(twitter)
        }
    }
});
```

If can sombody help me let me know... Thank you!

Comment: Im confused. You're missing some parts of the code. is "twitter" defined as anything? It's not present. Further more you defined the embed as "dark".

Comment: sorry, it works, i changed the code here and named it twitter, it works for me, i named it dark

Answer (score 0):

[`Message.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) returns a *[`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)* of attachments, while [`MessageEmbed.setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) requires a string (the url). I believe what you are looking for is [`Collection.prototype.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first), which will return the first [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) in the collection. From there, you can access the [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url) property.

```js
const dark = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setColor('#000000')
 .setDescription(`${message.content}\n`)
 .addField('\n')
 .setAuthor('Twitter')
 .setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
 .setFooter(
  'twitter',
  'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/564032243836780558/771614643159433226/Anonymous_emblem.svg.png'
 );
```

Comment: what about the other 2 problems? Also it prints error .setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: For future reference: only one problem per question. About your error, it means the user didn't send any attachments, so just handle that with an `||` operator or optional chaining. The second argument of `setAuthor` can be `message.author.displayAvatarURL()` for the pfp problem.

Comment: how can i handle that with ||? and what should i add? Also there is an error with your code TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined, URL is not defined, thats not because i didnt add an attachment

Comment: Will you answer?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" does not mean `url` is undefined, it means `message.attachments.first()` is undefined. And the only way for that to happen is if the collection is empty. You can handle that with `message.attachments.first()?.url` or `(message.attachments.first() || {}).url`. Both will return undefined if it cannot find any attachments, and thus handler the error.

Comment: so what i can do if there is not any attachments? I want if somebody send a text send the text and when somebody sends an attachment send the attachment with the text

Comment: That's what it's doing. If the argument for `setImage()` is undefined, it just won't send an image.

Comment: sorry for interapting you again, it doesn't send any attachments, sorry again :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223916/discussion-between-lioness100-and-blanky).